# Finding the median value from a List of objects using Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, median

I have two classes that are structured like this:

```
public class Company {
     private List<Person> person;
     ...
     public List<Person> getPerson() {
          return person;
     }
     ...
}

public class Person {
     private Double age;
     ...
     public Double getAge() {
          return age;
     }
     ...
}
```

Basically the Company class has a List of Person objects, and each Person object can get an Age value.

If I get the List of the Person objects, is there a good way to use Java 8 to find the median Age value among all the Person objects (Stream doesn't support median but is there anything else)?

```
Double medianAge;
if(!company.getPerson().isEmpty) {
     medianAge = company.getPerson() //How to do this in Java 8?
}
```

Comment: Simplest method, not the most efficient: sort the list, find the middle element.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the stream?

Comment: @JoeC Stream is just mentioned as something neat to use in my build, so I was wondering if there is something else among the current technologies that I could use for median.  Thanks.

Comment: Stream simplifies tasks which require iterating over all elements. In case of median you just need to make sure that elements are sorted and pick middle one or two middle ones.

Comment: If using Guava there's no need to reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StatsExplained#median-only-of-existing-values

Comment: Please have a look at this link which describes [how to find the median value from a list of objects using java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667989/finding-the-median-value-from-a-list-of-objects-using-java-8)

Answer (score 16):

You may use

```
List<Person> list = company.getPerson();
DoubleStream sortedAges = list.stream().mapToDouble(Person::getAge).sorted();
double median = list.size()%2 == 0?
    sortedAges.skip(list.size()/2-1).limit(2).average().getAsDouble():        
    sortedAges.skip(list.size()/2).findFirst().getAsDouble();
```

The advantage of this approach is that it doesn’t modify the list and hence also doesn’t rely on its mutability. However, it’s not necessarily the simplest solution.

If you have the option of modifying the list, you can use

```
List<Person> list = company.getPerson();
list.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Person::getAge));
double median = list.get(list.size()/2).getAge();
if(list.size()%2 == 0) median = (median + list.get(list.size()/2-1).getAge()) / 2;
```

instead.

Answer (score 9):

Obligatory Guava way.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.google.common.math.Quantiles;

...

List<Person> people = company.getPerson();
List<Double> ages = people.stream().map(Person::getAge).collect(Collectors.toList());
double median = Quantiles.median().compute(ages);
```

Though as of Guava 31.1 [Quantiles](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/math/Quantiles.html) is still annotated as [@Beta](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html).

Comment: everything there is `@Beta` for some hideous reason

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simplified version of @Holger's answer that also works for `IntStream` and `LongStream`, and avoids `NoSuchElementException` in the case of an empty stream:

```
int size = someList.size();

//replace 'XXX' with 'Int', 'Long', or 'Double' as desired
return someList.stream().mapToXXX(...).sorted()
    .skip((size-1)/2).limit(2-size%2).average().orElse(Double.NaN);
```

This will return `NaN` if the list is empty rather than throwing `NoSuchElementException`. If you'd prefer to throw a `NoSuchElementException` instead, simply replace `.orElse(Double.NaN)` with `.getAsDouble()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution in one stream using [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-)

```
double median = people.stream()
        .map(Person::getAge)
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                ages -> {
                    int count = ages.size();
                    if (count % 2 == 0) { // even number
                        return (ages.get(count / 2 - 1) + ages.get(count / 2)) / 2;
                    } else { // odd number
                        return ages.get(count / 2);
                    }
                }));
```

It doesn't modify the existing list or require them to be sorted.

Answer (score -2):

if the list is not sorted the following code can be used:

```
int middle = list.size()/2;
Integer value = list.stream().filter(i -> list.indexOf(i) == middle).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: This is not a solution -- you appear to be getting the middle element of the list, and saying yourself that you assume the list is not sorted. In that case, the middle element is not the median.
This is not correct code -- you are assuming there are one or more elements in the list who have the middle index. If the list has an uneven number of elements, that won't be the case, and get(0) will throw.
This is not efficient -- you are running through the entire list, then asking each element what index in the list it is. That is O(n^2).