# How would I make the application add all the values of the integers in the arraylist so I could find the median of each grade?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many grades do you want to input: ");

        int amount = scanner.nextInt();
        int i = 0;

        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (i < amount) {
            System.out.print("Enter a grade (between 0 and 100): ");
            myList.add(sc.nextInt());
            i++;
        }

        int highestNumber = Collections.max(myList);
        int lowestNumber = Collections.min(myList);

        System.out.println("The highest grade is: " + highestNumber);
        System.out.println("The lowest grade is: " + lowestNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: The median is nothing to do with addition. It's to do with sorting. Look it up!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43678244/2478398

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the median value from a List of objects using Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667989/finding-the-median-value-from-a-list-of-objects-using-java-8)

Answer (score 0):

your code already does that
you just have to add at the following at the end of your main to see your list

```
System.out.println(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the median.

- sort the array.
- if the array contains an odd number of elements, take the middle value of the array.
- if the array contains an even number, add the two values in the middle and divide by 2

So the median is the value such that there are just as many above it as below it.

```
a = {1,2,3,5,1000,2000,3000}
```

The median of the values in `a` is `5`